# Add VCL and Forms support to Delphi Winapi message loop application?

Tags: winapi, delphi-7, vcl

I contribute code to a Delphi 7 application hosted on GitHub. While the application is in Delphi, it was written more like a Winapi application with its own Message Loop, etc. All forms are either Windows resource files or dialogs created at run-time in the code. The standard Application and Forms handling is not present. Rather than do a full rewrite, I am curious if it is possible to add support for the VCL such that I can make use of standard Delphi Forms. It would be easier to add new forms using the standard Delphi tools such as the Forms editor but I am unsure if I can have the Delphi Application and forms events co-exist with the Winapi message loop in the code. The project is called TR4W in GitHub available here: https://github.com/n4af/TR4W

My search for the answer involved quite a bit of searching but I have never found anything on this specific problem. I suspect it may have to do with the obvious question of why one would use Delphi and not write the code for Forms support from the start.

Comment: If you look at the message loop managed by TApplication.Run you will see that there are VCL specific features implemented there. So your app's current message loop won't support those features. If you replaced the current message loop with the VCL message loop it's likely the existing forms will continue to work. But that won't be the case if the message loop is not standard.